# I want to assign values to a variable in range in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I want to assign values to my variable, so that it should contain all values greater than specific value. I am using `np.range`  but here also we need to pass argument as `np.range(start_range, end_range, Difference between two values)` .I want my variable to contain all values greater than `(start_range)`

I have dataframe which contains a column Score range 0-1.
Say i have created a function as below :

```
def get_data(Data, score):
    ......
    ......
```

Now when I call this function , I want all the records from my Dataframe that has score more than 0.8.

Is there any other way to assign the value in range?

Comment: That sounds like you may not quite understand how variables work. Why do you think you need your variable to contain all values greater than a specific number? What problem are you trying to solve by doing this?

Comment: Python doesn't support infinitely large data structures...maybe try Haskell?

Comment: There is also the issue that numbers go up to positive infinity... so you are probably looking for something else, not what you described in the question. Maybe just an `if x > start_range:`

Comment: @JoshFriedlander It does. It's called generator.

Comment: @user2357112- I have a data frame , that contains a column of score range 0-1. Now I am writing a function where I am passing the score variable. But while calling the function I want to pass the value of the score as it should contain only values >=0.8.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to return all values from your dataframe greater than a threshold (0.8). `range` is not the tool for this.

```
def get_data(df, score, column):
    """Return rows of Dataframe where 'column' has value greater than 'score'."""
    new_df = df.loc[df[column] > score]
    return new_df
```

```
>>> get_data(df, 0.8, 'Score')
```